# I am getting a Source error when importing @Chainlink. My project will compile. How can I avoid this error, or should I just ignore it?

Tags: error, brownie, chainlink, solidity-0.6.x, configuration

I do not know what the issue is as I am on version 0.6.6 Solidity both in my compiler and in my code, and I am using all of the same versions of the packages that Patrick used. I find it even more peculiar that my code compiles and downloads correctly. Is this just something that I should ignore and move on from?

Error: `Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File import callback not supported` So this is an error message that everyone gets when they follow the Lesson 6 tutorial, however, mine did not go away after I added my remapping to brownie-config.yaml

```
    dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linting issues
If you see something along the lines of:

```
ParserError: Source "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File not found.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

In your vscode, these and be safely ignored. However you can also add to your settings to ignore these.

1. Create a .vscode folder at the root of your project.
2. Create a file called settings.json
   Add the following code:

```
{
  "solidity.remappings": [
    "@chainlink/=/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2",
    "@openzeppelin/=/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2"
  ]
}
```

Or whatever version your @chainlink and @openzeppelin contracts need. For example:
[image]

[For more information see here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/blob/main/chronological-issues-from-video.md)

Comment: Thank you Patrick, this seemed to work for me. I had it in my .yaml file only.